# How to set Git branch protected in Github by default when create it

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I need to make branch protected directly when creating it. I know that I need to go to Setting and set it as protected from there, but what I'm looking for is to set the branch as protected automatically without the need to do that every time I create a new branch. I tried to find this feature in Github but seems not supported

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic and should be on this software thingy site instead.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz "software thingy site"?

Comment: @larsks I believe it's [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I should post my question in WebApps, I thought that such as question should be here. I posted my question as well , and hope find the answer here and there